# Show that any two different columns of an orthogonal matrix are orthogonal vectors, as are any two different rows.

Tags: linear-algebra

The solution in the manual is as follows:

If P is orthogonal and ci and cj are two different columns of P, then c′i cj is the element in row i and column j of P′P = I, so c′i cj = 0. If ri and rj are two different rows of P, then ri r′j is the element in row i and column j of PP′ = I′ = I, so again ri r′j = 0.

I am having a hard time understanding what this is trying to say: my concern comes about why c'i cj = 0 and similarly for the rows. If

Comment: What definition of orthogonal matrix do you use?

Comment: The "solution in the manual" is just a restatement of the question !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}C_1 & C_2 & C_3 \end{bmatrix}$ be a $3\times 3$ orthogonal matrix where $C_i'$s are its columns. What is $A^TA$? 
$A^TA=\begin{bmatrix}C_1^T\\C_2^T\\C_3^T\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}C_1 & C_2 & C_3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}C_1^TC_1 & C_1^TC_2 & C_1^TC_3\\C_2^TC_1 & C_2^TC_2 & C_2^TC_3\\C_3^TC_1 & C_3^TC_2 & C_3^TC_3 \end{bmatrix}=I_3=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\implies C_i^TC_j=\begin{cases}0; i\ne j\\1;i=j\end{cases}$ 
Can you generalize above for $n\times n$ orthogonal matrices and do the similar exercise for rows?

Comment: This really helped illustrate it in my mind, thank you.

Comment: @Nish: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

An orthogonal matrix is the inverse of its transpose So the product with its transpose is a unit matrix.

Thus in the product, the element $p_{kk}$ is the square of a column vector, $c_k^2=1$, and the element $p_{jk}$ with $j\ne k$ is the dot product $c_jc_k=0$.

Repeat the reasoning on the transposed matrix.